# javascript onclick create element (label)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently developing a webapp, draft link: http://webtrickssolutions.in/ayna/new-Building.html#

i have problem with javascript coding, when pressing on "OK" button, it should add a row underneath the filled data "Language" and "Text" / the new row should be Label. for example if i added two times:

English "BuildingName01" (delete icon) 
Arabic  "XXXXX05" (delete icon)

and it should remove the English and Arabic from the drop down menu as i cant select the language twice.

current javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       

        $('.del').live('click',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });

        $('.add').live('click',function(){
            $(this).val('Delete');
            $(this).attr('class','del');

            var appendTxt = "<tr><td><select class='form-control form-control-bottom lang' name='input_box_one[]'><option>Language</option><option>English</option><option>Hindi</option></select></td> <td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='add' value='Ok' /></td></tr>";

            $("#options-table tr:first").before(appendTxt);         
        });        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What old version of jQuery are you using that supports `live()`?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You did not ask any actual question here - you just told us that you _had_ a problem, followed by a description of what your script _should_ do. So what _is_ your problem? What have you done so far to implement this? What specific parts do you have trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

On click of the OK button you can remove the particular option:

```
var item = "Hindi";
$("select option:contains('"+item+"')").remove();
```

Comment: it should be dynamic, not always Hindi - depends on what user is choosing - after clicking OK it should be removed from the list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the specific element, this can be removed via

```
$("#selectBox option[value='English']").remove();
```

However, for this to be dynamic, you would have to first grab the value of the selected index:

```
var option = $('#selector :selected').val()
```

Following, remove this using a dynamic selector, like:

```
$("#selectBox2 option[value='" + option + "]")
```

EDIT: Updated Post:

I'd suggest that, the further down you go the more complex this object will be to maintain. Therefore, I suggest that instead of dynamically adding the element through a string, like so, you instead generate it using an array. This can be seen in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/13vfz8nt/). Obviously, this uses a newer version of jQuery, so can replace the 'On' with the 'Live' method.

This works by firstly creating a new select element:

```
var newSelect = $('<select/>');
```

Then, adds each element from the current dropdown as options to this select

```
$(this).parent().find("option:not(:selected)").each(function() {
    newSelect.append($('<option/>').html($(this).val()));
});
```

& Finally appending this to the document

```
$("#options-table").before(newSelect);
```

Comment: thank you Joel,, i am really beginner  in this - can you please let me know where exactly should i put these lines ?

Comment: No worries. I will create a js fiddle now and attach it to my answer.

Comment: Updated my post with an alternative way of maintaining this. Hope it helps.

Comment: appreciate it- thanks... looking forward to receive it :)

Comment: Should be available now :)